# MVC3 Using Non-PK as a foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a FK which reference another table's non PK:
Here is my table design:

Member

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [education_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Esos_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Passport_IC_No] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CDS_Account_No] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Nationality] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Date_Joined] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Contact_No] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Tax_File_No] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Terminated] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Termination_Reason] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Termination_Date] [date] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdatedDT] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

KPI_Inspection

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KPI_Inspection](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Esos_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [KPI_Score] [decimal](3, 2) NOT NULL,
```

I am trying to use Esos_ID as FK. It works just fine is mssql server. i have added the relationship.
However, whenever i updated my model in my edmx file (ASO .Net model) in Visual Studio, these two tables just won't connect, The Navigation Properties is blank, If you take a look at the screenshot below, you will see my Member table and KPI_Inspection Table are not connected with the Foreign key i created which is Esos_ID:

[My EDMX diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fde87.png)

i have tried to add change the Esos_ID (Member) Constraint type to unique key and Index and both of it does not seem to give me any success

However, when i used Member table PK which is id as the FK reference, the table connect to each other using the FK.
is it possible to use a non PK column as a FK reference?

Comment: A PK declares a UNIQUE NOT NULL. A FK references a declared UNIQUE NOT NULL. It says source subrows appear as target subrows as a UNIQUE NOT NULL. The column types must be the same. You don't say what declaration you actually want or is failing. Explain "updated my model in my edmx file" & "won;t connect". Please read & act on the manual re FKs & on [mcve]. Also this is a SO faq. Google my comments re googling many versions of a question.

Comment: Sorry for that, edited my question to be clearer

Comment: Your edit removed a lot of code.

Comment: So your table type in MySQL is InnoDB?

Comment: it's MySQL, i am using mssql server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You didn't answer @Namphibian re InnoDB.